# Add one parameter DI registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a class which have multiple constructor dependency. It's probably worth refactor, but later.

I know that Autofac can do it via following code:

```
builder.RegisterType<ConfigReader>()
       .As<IConfigReader>()
       .WithParameter("configSectionName", "sectionName");
```

It means *"Use `sectionName` when resolving parameter `configSectionName` and use default flow for the rest"*.

The problem is that in .Net core built in DI I din't find any way to do it except factory method that forces me to manually call `serviceProvider.GetService<IFoo>()` on every other parameter, which is pretty annoying.

Can it be expressed directly or I have to choose autofac/workarounds? My current nasty code is:

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IPollService, PollService>(provider => new PollService(
    provider.GetService<IEthereumSettings>(),
    provider.GetService<EthereumClientProvider>(),
    provider.GetService<ABIDeserialiser>(),
    provider.GetService<ConstructorCallEncoder>(),
    provider.GetService<IJsonSerializer>(),
    provider.GetService<ILogger>(),
    rootContractAddress));
```

I can add some type like `RootContractConfig` and register it but it seems ugly that I have to modify my API to make DI happy.

Comment: Built in DI was meant to be simple. Autofac should have a .Net Core extension that can replace the default DI an satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, the built-in DI in ASP.NET Core only supports a small set of features needed to get started. For more advanced scenarios, the built-in DI container can be replaced with a different DI container.

So if you want to use Autofac you can replace the built-in DI as [described in the ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#replacing-the-default-services-container) or [Autofac's documentation for ASP.NET Core integration](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html).